# Destroying fragments which are in a hierarchical relation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Well, consider the case where one fragment has two child fragments , as in when two fragments are declared in the main fragment xml how do you destroy the fragment? Will all three fragments be added to the back stack?

Consider the main fragment A and consider its class file..

```
 public class fragmentA extends Fragment {
public static FragmentC fragmentC;
private static View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(view!=null){
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container,
                false);

        fragmentC= (fragmentC) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.fragment_c);
    }catch(InflateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return view;

}
```

now consider fragment a's xml file fragment_a

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
                     android:name="com.example.FragmentB"
                    android:layout_width="320dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/FragmentC"
                    android:name="com.example.FragmentC"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

in the above scenario, how to destroy the fragment?? do we have to individually destroy all three fragments or do we have to destroy just fragment a and the rest will destroy itself? also all the work is being done in fragment B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is very simple..

all u got to  do is destroy each of the fragments as you move from the page 
Check below code
add this code to both the pages.. 
pdmf is a static reference to ur class(Fragment A or Fragment C)
and then call this code for both fragments when u move from fragment B

```
 public static void removeFragment() {
    try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity) activityContext).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove((Fragment)pdMF);

        ft.commit();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```